# Make objects fill remaining div vertically

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons located within a div, but I want them to take up the entire space remaining vertically.

Just now, it looks like this:

```
Header
---------------------------
BUTTON 1
BUTTON 2


---------------------------
FOOTER
```

How can I make the two submit buttons take up the entire space?

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main-content">
            <!--<div class="innerInstructions">Choose your direction.</div>-->
            <form action="app-web.php" method="get" class="main-form clocking">
                <input type="hidden" name="do" value="performclock" />
                <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="'.$uid.'" />
                <input type="submit" name="clockaction" value="IN &rarr;" accesskey="I" />
                <input type="submit" name="clockaction" value="&larr; OUT" accesskey="O" />
            </form>


    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div id="time">{time}</div>
</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:45px; bottom:48px; left:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:none;
}
#main-content {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
.clocking{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.clocking input[type="submit"]{
    /*width: 45%;*/
    /*padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;*/
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:#deb500;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You might want to create a table, put the buttons in it and on the columns (where you put the buttons) make it height:100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made a demo fiddle for you to take a look at

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZKqC/3)

This is the main Code

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

header,footer{
    height:10%;
}

form{
    height:80%;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    height:50%;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Had to remove elements (as Diodeus said below) but it now works great. Plus, the skyblue is a lovely colour :)

Comment: :D That is my favourite color, and it's easy to remember too

Answer (score 1):

By using `position:absolute;` on `#main-content` you are taking `#main-content` out of the layout. It acts as a separate layer, stopping the `#wrapper` from allowing the content to flow.

Remove this and add padding-bottom to `#wrapper` if you want it to take up more space vertically, or give `#wrapper` a fixed height.